# Using Async Storage for Localization

Tags: typescript, react-native, localization, local-storage, asyncstorage

I have 2 different APIs that I use for localization. These return json.

```
getEnLoc() //400kb
getEsLoc() //400kb
```

I want to call them on App.ts while the app is being ready for running and write the returned answer(json object) to async storage. Afterwards, while the any page is being translated, the key-values ​​in the local storage will be checked.

```
// In App.ts
AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', getEnLoc())
// In Home.tsx
const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
```

What do you think about this logic? Do you think it causes loss of performance?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use only the language key in AsyncStorage like 'en', 'en_US', or 'tr_TR'. You should write language JSON files. For example en.json. I use this class structure for localization.

```
import { NativeModules, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { strings } from 'res';

class LanguageHelper {
  currentLanguage = null;
  currentStrings = null;

  init() {
    this.currentLanguage = this.determineDeviceLanguage();
    this.setCurrentString();
  }

  setCurrentString() {
    switch (this.currentLanguage) {
      case 'tr_TR':
        this.currentStrings = require("./tr.json");
        break;
      default:
        this.currentStrings = require("en.json");
    }
  }

  determineDeviceLanguage() {
    // Determine device language
    const language =
      Platform.OS === 'ios'
        ? NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale ||
          NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0]
        : NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier;

    return language;
  }
}

const LanguageProvider = new LanguageHelper();

export default LanguageProvider;
```

The en.json like that.

```
{
    "title": "Hello World";
}
```

In your App.js file, you import this class.

```
import LanguageProvider from './LanguageHelper';

const App () => {
    useEffect(() => {
    LanguageProvide.init(); // Init language
}, []);
    return(/* Your components */)
}
```

Then you can use this localized string where you want after importing.
For example,

```
LanguageProvider.currentStrings.title
```

Comment: I already have structure like this but it works with .json files these take place on project.
Now I have to get tr_TR.json file from external API. For example I have to call http://api.example.com/get-tr-loc-file to get localizations online. If I don't use async storage, I need to call API for every string.

Comment: I think AsyncStorage is a bad idea for storing big data. I think you can take localization JSON object from API when the app opens. Then save it a class in the app like LanguageProvider. Then you can use the class for every string. In this way, you don't need to call API every string but call once.